# Convert my MAC Address into byte array when build packet

Tags: c#, .net, packet

I want to build simple `DHCP packet` and one of the protocol oprion is `client mac address` (option 61), so i have my mac address:

```
string macAddress = "00:14:22:18:81:11";
```

and i want to put it in my packet array (6 bytes), this is what i have try and i wonder how to do that (i try to convert my string into byte[] but this array length is 24)

```
        // Set requested ip address - 61
        index += DHCPMessageTypeLength;
        packetArrayBytes[index] = 61; // option 
        packetArrayBytes[index + 1] = 7; // length
        packetArrayBytes[index + 2] = 1; // hardware type Ethernet
        packetArrayBytes[index + 3] = ?; // mac
        packetArrayBytes[index + 4] = ?; // mac
        packetArrayBytes[index + 5] = ?; // mac
        packetArrayBytes[index + 6] = ?; // mac
        packetArrayBytes[index + 7] = ?; // mac
        packetArrayBytes[index + 8] = ?; // mac
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my proposal:

```
List<byte> packet = new List<byte>();
packet.AddRange(new byte[] { 61, 7, 1 });
packet.AddRange(macAddress.Split(':').Select(b => Convert.ToByte(b, 16)));

Array.Copy(packet.ToArray(), 0, packetArrayBytes, DHCPMessageTypeLength, packet.Count);
```

Comment: macAddress.Split(':').Select(b => Convert.ToByte(b)) gives errors for me when the string contains letters (A,B,C,D,E,F) :(

Comment: @Bosiwow Thanks for pointing this out, I forgot to specify base 16 for hex conversion. See edited answer.